# Cannot read property 'question' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i'm getting the data in console.log, but when ever im describing the `getQuestion[0].question` at the steps it is showing undefined. what i'm doing wrong here please help me thanks in advance

```
function App() {
 const [getQuestion, setQuestion] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios
  .get('************')
  .then(function (response) {
   const questionsList = response.data.question
   setQuestion(questionsList)
});
},[])
console.log(getQuestion)

 const steps = [
{
  id: '1',
  message: getQuestion[0].question
  trigger: '2',
},
{
  id: '2',
  message: getQuestion[1].question
  trigger: '3',
}]
}
```

the `console.log(getQuestion)` shows these:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's because your initial state is []. Your steps assignment executes BEFORE the API call completes, therefore accessing an element of the empty array returns undefined.

Your console.log statement likely also logs "[]" just before you get the exception.

Comment: How to make api call executes first in  the code?

Comment: If you care about "steps" rather than "questionsList" you should keep steps in the state (not questionsList). So make a function that returns the steps array based on a parameter. Call this after the API is done and put the result of that call into state.

Comment: Check out the other answer also.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is about knowing the distinction the between what all things in `React` happen synchronously and asynchronously.

`useEffect` may be running before the execution of `steps`, but your `setQuestion` is an asynchronous function in nature. So, when you are defining `steps` your `getQuestion` is `[]`. So when you do `getQuestion[i]` where `i` = `0` or `1`, it breaks.

I think you can achieve the same structure of `steps` with little changes.

```js
const steps = getQuestion.map(({ question }, index) => ({
  id: index + 1,
  message: question,
  trigger: index + 2
}));
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
i intialized the code and i got this error ..

Comment: Suman - Please paste your whole code snippet please. Also, I understand you might be new to asking questions, but this is a very silly debug thing from what the error looks. It means someplace you are doing `obj.message` where `obj` is either `null` or `undefined`. If you could check that once. (`obj` is just a random name, you could have had any other way)